# Optimizing a combination of update and select query using JAVA

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, optimization

I have one update query which I am updating using JAVA. It is connected to a Oracle SQL database. It is a combination of an update and select query.

Query: "Update table1 set col1 = 'true', col2= current_timestamp where table1.col1 <> 'true' and table1.col3 in (select col3 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3 where table2.trdate is null or table2.trdate >= current_timestamp group by table1.col3 )

(select col3 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3 where table2.trdate is null or table2.trdate >= current_timestamp group by table1.col3 ) -> Output of this query will be more 10 million rcords.

select table1.col3 where table1.col1 <> 'true' and table1.col3 in (select table1.col3 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3 where table2.trdate is null or table2.trdate >= current_timestamp group by table1.col3 ) -> Output of this query will be around 30k rcords.

trdate is a timestamp.
col3 is a varchar and is connecting the two tables using join.

The above update query is taking lot of time (more than 6-7 hours) and is blocking the database.
Can someone suggest any better approach to optimize the query?

I am thinking to split the process into batches but since there are more than 10 million records, they will be using my space. Can someone help?

Comment: change from IN() to EXISTS() and change "table2.trdate is null" to an expression you can create an index on, be sure there is an index on both tables's col3.

Comment: How many rows in table1?

Comment: @p3consulting yes index is there on both col3, does adding index on col table2.trdate can help?

Comment: @BobC total rows in table1 are more than 40 million.

Comment: NULL values are not in a single column index, so answer is no: adding an index on trdate alone will not help here. An index on a compound like (trdate,1) will contains NULL trdate.

Comment: @p3consulting So you mean compound index can help? and what is this 1 you are referring in "compound like (trdate,1) ". I am sorry but I am not aware much on this topic.

Comment: "1" can be anything, even another non-nullable column if you have usage of such an index in other queries. The (column, constant) as an index is just a trick to have an index including also the rows where column IS NULL.
But anyway the presence of the index is just a possible improvement that will depend on the statistics of the values in the indexed column, if anyway ORACLE sees that the criteria will select a significant % of the data so that full scan is still more efficient, the index will not be used.

Comment: select col3 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3 where table2.trdate is null or table2.trdate >= current_timestamp group by table1.col3

If table1.col3 is unique but table2.col3 is not unique then can I remove group by?